# css chrome and safari issue

Tags: html, css

There is link on top right saying "Advance Search". It does not show at its appropriate position on Chrome and Safari browser. It works fine with Firefox and IE.
[click here to see](http://www.tafrehmela.com)

Here is the class I m using for that link:

```
.asearch {
margin-left: -210px;
margin-top: 20px;
position: absolute;
      }
```

I want this link to be shows exact under neath of input search text box on white whiteground.

Please guide.
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I got by adding right:140px using Chrome's developer tools. Make sure you use 'right:140px' NOT 'margin-right:140px'

[image: Chrome]

Comment: what is the difference between "margin-right" and "right". And by adding right code it did move the link but not at its right direction as it shows in the screenshot you posted. Also try to add this code in firefox as well and see if it moves it right in ff as well.

Comment: right determines the location of the right-most edge of the element, margin-right determines the buffer between the right most edge and the next element. Make sure you remove the 'margin-right' property from your asearch class and it should then work with the 'right:140px'

Comment: Cool, looks like that worked for you :)

Comment: well, right:150px works perfectly fine. But I wonder if that shows good to all screen resolution though ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're very welcome Hassan. It should be fine for all resolutions as long as your search box is the same distance from the edge.